# Parenthesis for JOIN clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
WITH 
t1(col) AS(
    VALUES
    (1),(2),(3)
),
t2(col) AS(
    VALUES
    (1),(3)
),
t3(col) AS(
    VALUES
    (1),(2)
)

SELECT * FROM ((t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.col = t2.col)
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1.col = t3.col);
```

I often see queries written this way (I mean parenthesis in SELECT).

Is there any difference between above and without parenthesis:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.col = t2.col
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1.col = t3.col;
```

?

Comment: Well some databases (e.g. MS Access) actually require parentheses like this.  For other databases it is optional.

Comment: I always considered it a nuisance that MS Access requires the parentheses and sometimes it is hard to get that syntax right :-) I suggest not to use them in other DBMS. The queries are more readable without them.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - Yes I also think so, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Parentheses *can* make a difference in `JOIN` statements.  In fact, sometimes they are necessary (I'll give an example of that later).

In your particular case, the parentheses are redundant because:

```
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN 
     t2
     ON t1.col = t2.col LEFT JOIN
     t3
     ON t1.col = t3.col
```

Is interpreted as:

```
FROM (t1 LEFT JOIN 
      t2
      ON t1.col = t2.col
     ) LEFT JOIN
     t3
     ON t1.col = t3.col
```

Because this interpretation is to from left-to-right.  Incidentally, this is also how arithmetic expressions are interpreted:  `a + b - c - d` is interpreted as `((a + b) - c) - d)`.  Exactly the same idea.

And this is how the second query is written.

But consider these two versions:

```
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN 
     t2
     ON t1.col = t2.col INNER JOIN
     t3
     ON t2.col = t3.col
```

(Note the last join condition changed to be between `t2` and `t3`)

And what looks similar:

```
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN 
     (t2 INNER JOIN
      t3
      ON t2.col = t3.col
     )
     ON t1.col = t2.col
```

Result in different results. In particular, the first keeps only rows in `t1` that match in `t3`.  The second keeps all rows in `t1`.

I should also point out that although the syntax of the previous example has to change due to the `on` clause, it *could* be written with `natural join` (which I abhor) as:

```
from t1 left natural join t2 inner join t3
```

versus:

```
from t1 left natural join (t2 inner join t3)
```

assuming that the join columns are unique to the table pairs.

I will also say that I do not think that commas in the `FROM` clause are common, except for code written in MS Access, which requires them.  They are rarely seen in SQL written for other databases (in my experience).

Answer (score 2):

Semantically, the part of the BNF -syntax look like:

```
tbl_expr := tbl_expr 'JOINOP' tbl_expr ;
```

, Where `tbl_expr` is "table expression". (such as `SELECT ... FROM ...` , OR `VALUES(...)` ), and `JOINOP` is one of the JOIN operators.

In SQL, this part of the syntax look like:

```
tbl_expr := tbl_expr 'TJOIN' tbl_expr 'ON' bool_expr ;
```

, where TJOIN is one of {`[INNER] JOIN` , `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` , `RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN` , `FULL [OUTER] JOIN` }

, or: the special case (without a join condition) :

```
tbl_expr := tbl_expr 'XJOIN' tbl_expr ;
```

, where XJOIN is `CROSS JOIN`

And, there is an additional syntax rule:

```
tbl_expr := '(' tbl_expr ')' ;
```

So, you can put parentheses around any `tbl_expr`, just as you would do with scalar expressions. The `JOINOP`s all associate left-to-right, so you could use parentheses to overrule that.

And `NATURAL JOIN` is syntactic sugar. (and semantic poison, IMHO. Stay away from it!)

The `USING(column_list)` variant also is syntactic sugar, and less dangerous. But it is just another syntactic variant of the `TJOIN`